# Duplicate primary key error while inserting data in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm inserting data in mysql database with JPA, but i get this error!

```
Query: InsertObjectQuery(eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.KPI.KPI@7a363633)
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO ReceivedPacketsStats (id, CodeRate, DataRate, Frequency, Signalisation, Lsnr, NodeMacAddress, MessageID, Modulation, Nature, Rssi, Size, Status, Time, timestamp, TypeMessage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [16 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.KPI.KPI@7a363633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.KPI.KPI.persist(KPI.java:138)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.KPI.KPI.<init>(KPI.java:126)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.PacketFormatConverter.handleStats(PacketFormatConverter.java:275)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.PacketFormatConverter.NodeKPipePacket2RawData(PacketFormatConverter.java:77)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.LoraNodeKConnector.receive(LoraNodeKConnector.java:108)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.NodeKPipe.receive(NodeKPipe.java:111)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.TunnelPipe.receive(TunnelPipe.java:103)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.UpstreamTunnel.filter(UpstreamTunnel.java:82)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.AbstractTunnel$Filterer.work(AbstractTunnel.java:263)
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.AbstractTunnel$Worker.run(AbstractTunnel.java:237)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO ReceivedPacketsStats (id, CodeRate, DataRate, Frequency, Signalisation, Lsnr, NodeMacAddress, MessageID, Modulation, Nature, Rssi, Size, Status, Time, timestamp, TypeMessage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [16 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.KPI.KPI@7a363633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1313)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1585)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1500)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
    ... 41 more
11:03:16.339 [UpstreamTunnel-Filterer-[0]] WARN  eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.AbstractTunnel - Exception in UpstreamTunnel-Filterer-[0]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:176) ~[eclipselink.jar:2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.KPI.KPI.persist(KPI.java:141) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.KPI.KPI.<init>(KPI.java:126) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.PacketFormatConverter.handleStats(PacketFormatConverter.java:275) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.PacketFormatConverter.NodeKPipePacket2RawData(PacketFormatConverter.java:77) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.LoraNodeKConnector.receive(LoraNodeKConnector.java:108) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.NodeKPipe.receive(NodeKPipe.java:111) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.TunnelPipe.receive(TunnelPipe.java:103) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.UpstreamTunnel.filter(UpstreamTunnel.java:82) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.AbstractTunnel$Filterer.work(AbstractTunnel.java:263) ~[classes/:?]
    at eu.telecombretagne.loraFabian.nodeK.tunnel.AbstractTunnel$Worker.run(AbstractTunnel.java:237) [classes/:?]
```

Help me to solve that, thank you!

Comment: show the code that gives you the error, and format the question please

Comment: How are you generating Id first of all?

Comment: the Id is a generatedValue with JPA automatically

Comment: Thats true, What generator you are using, like Tablegenerator, Sequence generator. In data base you already have an entry with what Id generator has generated.  Update the generator accordingly manually, or remove entry from the database.

Comment: I'm using sequence generator

Answer (score 1):

- You are passing id is 1 for object ReceivedPacketsStats.
- But in Database ReceivedPacketsStats table has already record present with id is 1.
- That's why it is throwing MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1'.

Comment: the id is incremented automatically, and i tried to delete data from database and execute the program but the problem is not solved !

Comment: @mounir Follow below steps:  First truncate your table using truncate tableName; then try to execute your program

Comment: i tried to delete data from database and the problem is not solved, i create the table from java code so automatically when i run the program the table is empty

Comment: @mounir after execute your code..Have u checked table..How many records are there??

Comment: yes, i tried to send just one packet to the database, normally i found 2 records(the request and the response) but i found just the request, i think phpmyadmin try to add the response with the same id

Comment: @mounir That is your problem...request and response both storing with same id that's why it creating problem for you..

Comment: Ranjeet but i'm using JPA to create a dynamic id value with @GeneratedValue, normally the id is incremented ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all,

I  solved the problem by deleting the index id in phpmyadmin !

Answer (score -1):

You are passing explicitly the id of the record you are inserting.

Probably you are passing an already existing id. Check it with the data present on database.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what question header says!

Comment: the id is  a GeneratedValue with JPA:
Id
Column(name="id")
GeneratedValue

and after that, i persist data with entityManagerFactory using JPA in mysql database